# Odoo tree view with create_date

Tags: odoo

Do you know how to insert the column `create_date` on the Odoo Customers Tree View? It would let me see the most recent clients created on the system.
Thank you,
Eduardo

Comment: field "create_date" exists on database (table res_partner) but does not exist on the list of avaliable fields to be added in a tree view.

Comment: These are the fields which are by default therein Odoo. So as to use, in tree view just open the desired view and add `<field name="create_date"/>`.

Answer (score 5):

for insert the column create_date on the Odoo Customers Tree View follow the following steps:-

1:- inherit in .py file

```
from openerp import models, fields, api, _


class ResPartner(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    create_date = fields.Datetime("Date")
```

2:- extend res.partner tree view.

```
<record id="view_inherit_res_partner_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">res.partner</field>
    <field name="model">res.partner</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_tree"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='function']" position="before">
            <field name="create_date"/>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would advise against changing the _order attribute on the model as that changes the order in the database, which may not be what you are trying to achieve. Instead, add a default_order="create_date desc" attribute to the tree element of the list view. In the arch:

```
<tree position="attributes">
    <attribute name="default_order">create_date desc</attribute>
</tree>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Follow this step**

**1/** Inherit res_partner class.
In your .py file, add this code.[redefine _order attribute]

```
class res_partner(osv.Model):
    _inherit = "res.partner"
    _order = "create_date desc"
res_partner()
```

**2/**  In your view file, inherit the partner's tree-view and add create_date field.

```
<record id="view_partner_tree_extended" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">res.partner.extended</field>
    <field name="model">res.partner</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_tree"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='display_name']" position="before">
            <field name="create_date"/>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

**Note** : No need to add create_date field in python file because it comes from osv.model base class.
         **_order** atttribute is used for sort the records as your requirement.

Restart server and update your module.

Hope It will work for you !!

Let me know if you have any query.

Answer (score 0):

```
As create_date is Automatic fields in Odoo, you can directly access it in the tree view.

Example:-

<record id="customer_list_view" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">customer.tree</field>
  <field name="model">bank.customer</field>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
  <tree string="Customer View">
    <field name="name"/>
    <field name="contact"/>
    <field name="create_date"/> // Directly access from database(no need to declare in model)
  </tree>
  </field>
</record>
```

Comment: Hi, when I inserted the string "<field name="create_date"/>" on my res.partner.tree, the following error occurr: "Error occurred while validating the field(s) arch: Invalid XML for View Architecture!".

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you'll use xpath and inherit the tree view from the customers. The following xml should work:

```
<record id="inherit_customer_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">res.partner.tree.inherit</field>
        <field name="model">res.partner</field>
<field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_tree" />
<field name="arch" type="xml">
    <xpath expr="//field[@name='display_name']" position="before">
        <field name="create_date" />
    </xpath>
</field>
    </record>
```

Comment: the field "create_date" exists on database (table res_partner) but does not exist on the list of avaliable fields to be added in a tree view,

Comment: I tested the code and it worked for me.
Can you provide the code you used?

Answer (score 0):

To insert create_date into the tree view

first create a field with the same name ['create_date'] in your .py file

'create_date':fields.datetime('Create Date')

then put it in your tree view. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Write  code in your specific tree view

```
<record id="my_tree_view_id" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">my.mode.view.tree</field>
        <field name="model">my.model</field>
        <field name="mode">primary</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="My model tree view">
                <field name="name" />
                <field name="product_count" />
                <field name="write_date" />
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Using the write_date in field tag then print  date with time in specific tree  view.

Answer (score 0):

you can direct declare in xml. No need to define .py file. Because create_date is a odoo magic field. so, you can declare directly in tree view.

Answer (score 0):

```
<data>
  <xpath expr="//field[@name='display_name'][not(ancestor::field)]" position="after">
    <field name="create_date"/>
  </xpath>
  <xpath expr="//field[@name='create_date'][not(ancestor::field)]" position="after">
    <field name="create_uid"/>
  </xpath>
</data>
```

Place this code in a view using the developers tool button in the partner tree 
create_date = date
create_uid  = the user that created the partner

Answer (score 0):

In Odoo/OpenERP we can inherit or use existing modules object/class/model and views. We can also inherit single field of existing modules. The question is why we need such inheritance.

**The purpose of inheritance or why we need inheritance is given below:**

1. To change attributes of some fields which exists on existing/custom
   model (e.g. making fields readonly,invisible)
2. To add/modify/delete old or new fields in existing/custom model
   (e.g. Product, Sales, HR, Fleet Management, Attendance modules model
   etc)
3. We can also add buttons in already existing/custom model (form and
   tree) view by using inheritance

Comment: To get complete guide and code about inheritance [link](https://www.reddit.com/user/Sehrishnaz47/comments/80a3vo/inheritance_in_models_and_views/)